# Does $f\Big(x+\frac{1}{n}\Big) \to f(x)$ for a.e. x as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Let $f$ be a bounded measurable function on the real line, then is it true that $f\Big(x+\frac{1}{n}\Big) \to f(x)$ for a.e. $x$ as $n \to \infty$

I found a result where this is true for $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$, and I think in general it may not be true, but I'm not able to find a counter.

Comment: If that is really true for $f\in L^1$ it should be true for any measurable function which is bounded, right? Since boundedness implies integrable on each set $[-n,n]$ and then you can check the property there for each $n$.

Comment: boundedness may not imply $L^1(\Bbb{R})$

Comment: If $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ then $e^{-x^2} f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Does this help you? Edit: Or what LeBtz wrote.

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal. Of course not. But bounded implies $f\chi_{[-N,N]}\in L^1$ for each $N$. Hence, almost every $x\in [-N,N]$ satisfies the condition above. Since it is possible to cover $\mathbb R$ with a countable number of intervals of sort $[-N,N]$ it must be true for a.e. $x$.

Comment: @aes do you mean to say $e^{-(x+\frac{1}{n})^2}\cdot f(x+\frac{1}{n})\to e^{-x^2}f(x)$ in $L^1$ norm $\implies f(x+\frac{1}{n})\to f(x)$?

Comment: @aes if you know the answer then I request you to please post so that I can understand.

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal My comment was to the same effect as LeBtz's. If you know the result already for $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then it follows for $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. If you mean that you know convergence in $L^1$ norm, then that is different --- perhaps edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Could you please indicate where you found a proof for $L^1$ functions? Because it is well known that $f(x +1/n)$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$, but this only yields a.e. convergence **for a subsequence**. If you know the result for $L^1$, it will easily follow for bounded measurable functions and then even for **arbitrary** measurable ones. But I don't really believe this to be true, so I think the result should already fail for $L^1$.

Comment: @PhoemueX It is available in Real Analysis by Stein Sakarchi , maybe in $L^p$ chapter.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is NO. We construct an example when $f(x+1/n)\not\to f(x)$
on a set with positive measure.

Set up a variable base number system: for $0\le x<1$, let
$$
x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k(x)}{10^{1+2+\ldots+k}}
\quad\text{where $0\le a_k(x)<10^k$},
$$
and let
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \exists k ~ a_k(x)=0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}
\\ \end{cases}
$$

Let $A=\big\{ x\in[0,1): \forall k ~ a_k(x)\ge2 \big\}$; that is the set of
those numbers that do not contain the digits $0$ and $1$ at all. This
set has positive measure: $\lambda(A)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty
\left(1-\frac2{10^k}\right)>0$. We show that for every $x\in A$, we
have $f(x)=0$ and $f(x+1/n)=1$ for infinitely many $n$.

It is trivial that $f(x)=0$ for $x\in A$.

Take an arbitrary $x\in A$; We need infinitely many positive integers
$n$ such that $f(x)=1$. Take an integer $k>3$; we want to change the
$k$th digit to $0$ or $1$ by adding $1/n$ to $x$. Of course we can
write $1/n$ in our number system; we can see that
$$
a_k(x+1/n) = a_k(x)+a_k(1/n)
\quad\text{or}\quad
a_k(x+1/n) = a_k(x)+a_k(1/n)+1, 
$$
depending the carry from the lower significant digits. Hence, it
suffices to enforce $a_k(x)+a_k(1/n)=10^k$.

Let $b=10^k-a_k(x)$ and take an integer $n$ such that
$$
a_k(1/n)=b, \quad\text{i.e.}\quad
\frac{b}{10^{1+2+\ldots+k}} \le \frac1n < \frac{b+1}{10^{1+2+\ldots+k}},
$$
or equivalently
$$
\frac{10^{1+2+\ldots+k}}{b+1}
< n \le 
\frac{10^{1+2+\ldots+k}}{b}.
$$
Such an $n$ exists if
$$
\frac{10^{1+2+\ldots+k}}{b}-\frac{10^{1+2+\ldots+k}}{b+1} > 1;
$$
this is true because
$$
b(b+1) < 10^{2k} < 10^{1+2+\ldots+k}.
$$
Therefore the desired $n$ exists. Since $n>10^{1+\dots+(k-1)}$, the set of
the constructed values for $n$ is unbounded.

So, $f(x+1/n)\not\to f(x)$ in the set $A$ with positive measure.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice construction. My only question left is: How did you come up with this idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that question may come from Lusin's theorem.

It states that for every measurable function there exists measurable (non-zero measure) subset where it is is continuous. So function is not necessary continuous on its entire set.
Let $$f(x) = 1_{{sqrt(x)\in Q}}$$ and $0$ otherwise.

So $f(x)$ is bounded and measurable but not continuous in rational points that are full squares.

I am not sure that a.e. states for. If it is "almost everywhere", i.e. set has to have non-zero measure then my example is not valid.

**UPDATE**

I have looked up on Lusin theorem variants.
Proposition as it stated is current post **not true**... However,
the following statement is true:

If $f \in L^1(\lambda)$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then there is a continuous function $g \in L^1(\lambda)$ so that $$\int_{R} |f - g| d\lambda \lt \epsilon$$
I.e. measurable function from $L^1$ can be approximated by continuous function from $L^1$. It is not point-wise convergence, but weak convergence on measure.
[See "7 Theorem" here](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4225/2013/lusin.pdf).

Comment: Yes, "a.e." means "almost everywhere" or "almost every".